# How does one define a if then else expression in Isabelle?

Tags: functional-programming, isabelle, theorem-proving, hol

It complains to me I have a parsing error but I can't find in the manual what the right syntax is suppose to be...

```
  | "my_function x b (Cons3 y) = if x=y then b else (Cons3 y)"
```

error:

```
Inner syntax error⌂
Failed to parse prop
```

Answer (score 2):

You need brackets:

```
  | "my_function x b (Cons3 y) = (if x=y then b else (Cons3 y) )"
```

for some reason.

Found an example and copied it from this resource:

https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/functions.pdf

Answer (score 2):

In the HOL object logic, the `if-then-else`, `case`, and `let` constructs have as low a precedence as quantifiers, which requires  additional enclosing  parentheses  in  the  context  of  most  other  operations. Please have a look at https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2019/doc/logics.pdf, page 10.